# Prove that $X'X$ is rank-preserving of X

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrix-rank

Given $X_{nxp}$ of rank p, we know that $(X'X)^{-1}$ exists because $X'X$ also has rank $p$. But how do you prove that $X'X$ has rank $p$ (it is rank-preserving of $X$)? What properties can you use to prove this?

Clarification: $X'$ is the transpose of $X$, and the values of $X$ are real.

Comment: Is $X'$ the transpose of $X$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes

Comment: And does $X$ have real entries?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes. just updated the question

Comment: Then prove that $X'Xv=0$ iff $Xv=0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown could you explain how you would show that those two null spaces are equal?